# How to declare instance in SWIFT like Objective-C?

Tags: swift, ios8, uicollectionview, uitextview, uicollectionviewcell

I am doing reading app by using UICollectionView in SWIFT. I am receiving two errors. 
1. I couldn't create instance for another class, to access that class property, like in
Objective-C. If I create and run means, I am getting Fatal Error.
2. When it runs, automatically view dimension cannot change through coding. But in Objective-C, I can. In swift, if I run my code, after scroll to three more cell, view dimensions get change. But in Objective-C, view changes its dimension when its loaded. I don't know what mistake i did, Kindly guide me!

My Objective-C coding is below:

```
//class_one.h


//class_one.m
@interface class_one ()

@end

@implementation class_one

class_one_tblvwcell * cell_fire    //Global Declaration (another class instance)

         :
         :

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:
(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"wow";

    cell_fire = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier 
forIndexPath:indexPath];

cell_fire.readView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];

return cell_fire

}

@end

//class_one_tblvwcell.h

@interface class_one_tblvwcell : UITableViewCell
{
  @property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *readView;

}
@end


//class_one_tblvwcell.m
#import "class_one_tblvwcell.m"

@implementation class_one_tblvwcell

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)layoutSubviews {
    [super layoutSubviews];
    readView.frame = CGRectMake(0,50,220,220); //when prog runs, automatically view 
                                               //dimensions set to this position.

}

@end

//My Swift Coding:

class read_page: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource,UICollectionViewDelegate 
{
  @IBOutlet var reading_collection_view: UICollectionView!

var cell_fire = to_reading_cell() // ERROR 1: FATAL ERROR - VALUE NIL UNWRAPPING

 override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {

     super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
  }

 func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: 
 Int) -> Int {

      return 10  
  }

 func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath 
   indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

  cell_fire = story_collection_view.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("to_read", 
  forIndexPath: indexPath) 

  return cell_fire
  }

//to_reading_cell class

class to_reading_cell: UICollectionViewCell {
  @IBOutlet var read_txt_vw: UITextView!

  override func  layoutSubviews() {

    super.layoutSubviews()

    read_txt_vw.backgroundColor = UIColor.purpleColor() 
//COLOR gets load when its run

    read_txt_vw.frame = CGRectMake(0, 50, 320, read_txt_vw.contentSize.height)

//ERROR 2 The above line is executing after three more scrolls how to display from 
//first load.

    }
  }
```

Comment: Read the free book by apple.

Comment: I am new to swift! Guide me!

Comment: Download the free book. Your first guide is yourself. It's how learning works.